# Octopus Deploy create two tasks when deploying

Tags: octopus-deploy

Is it possible to break a single deployment step into two tasks? I want one tasks to contain all our windows services and happen 3 days later. The rest of the projects need to go into another task that happens immediately. Currently we are manually selecting some projects not to deploy and clicking deploy. Then we start another deployment and deselect all projects and select the ones we skipped in the first deployment. It seems like this could be done through the API but I would prefer to do it with built in functionality or an add-on.

Answer (score 1):

You should check this step : [Wait Until Step](https://library.octopusdeploy.com/step-templates/c8781255-615a-4092-99f1-82ddefdb6d6b/actiontemplate-wait-until-time) ,
Or this one [Wait Step](https://library.octopusdeploy.com/step-templates/c69b03c9-bfa1-41ab-a712-ba74dc0512b1/actiontemplate-wait)

Comment: Would I just make it so the next step doesn't wait for this to finish?

Comment: @MaxYoung both steps freezes the entire process.
One of them delay for given amount of the seconds , the other wait for the specified resume date.

Comment: I suppose I could put all the services as the last processes and then put this  process separating everything from the services. Would prefer if the order didn't matter though since others might not know they cant add to the end.